# Get a custom header in angular $http from web api controller

Tags: angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api, response

I am trying to pass a piece of information along with my content in my HttpResponseMessage like:

```
        string jsonFiles = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listFiles);
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent(jsonFiles)
        };
        response.Headers.Add("Key", "Value");

        return response;
```

However in my angular call and response I cannot see the "Key" header in response.config.headers or response.headers. Any idea why?

```
  $http.get("/api/Locker").then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.headers);
        console.log(response.config.headers);
  });
```

In my  Startup.cs I do have:

```
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
```

Comment: Can you try using the success overload with 4 parameters (response, status, headers, config)  and access the headers?

Comment: undefined. However if I use just the response the response object has all of those properties on it. Response.config.headers has a Accepted header and a Bearer header but not the one I added.

Comment: As per the documentation response.config returns the config used while sending the request. response.headers is a function. Try using response.headers("Key") and see if it helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm Sarathy if you want to make an answer I will accept

Comment: Added as an answer. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation `response.config` returns the config used while sending the request. `response.headers` is a function. Try using `response.headers("Key")` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly add the custom header to your CORS policy, or AngularJS will be unable to read it. Change this:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

To this:

```
var policy = new CorsPolicy
{
    AllowAnyHeader = true,
    AllowAnyMethod = true,
    AllowAnyOrigin = true,
    SupportsCredentials = true
};

policy.ExposedHeaders.Add("MyHeader");

app.UseCors(new CorsOptions
{
    PolicyProvider= new CorsPolicyProvider
    {
        PolicyResolver = c => Task.FromResult(policy)
    }
});
```

Comment: Then you have to inspect your HTTP response using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and check if both your custom header and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header are present and correct. Also, always make sure that your call to `app.UseCors` is made **before** any other OWIN middleware in the pipeline.

Comment: I had been doing that. Sarathy's answer in the comments is what worked for me. Didn't have to change anythign with CORS.

Answer (score 0):

I am using WebApi version 5.2.3.  To export a response header, you can try creating a custom attribute, for example

```
public class CustomHeadersAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "<Your Custom Key>");
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

Then on your controller or wherever you need it, just add

```
[CustomHeaders]
public HttpResponseMessage GetMethod() { ... }
```